# (EXCEL) How to select a range with the number of columns (I put the number as an input)?

Tags: excel, indexing, count, conditional-statements, average

I have a column o number like 7,11,14 etc.
I want to take average of last 7,11,14.. columns as an example.

When I want to take average it seems as AVERAGE(B3:B20). In this average it seems that it takes the last 18 columns,

I want this to be like this: when I enter 11 it will be AVERAGE(B10:B20) considering the last columns is B20

How can I do that without using macro?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are confusing column and row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `OFFSET()` formula:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(B3,0,0,11))
```

This will return the average of range starting from `B3` and spanning 11 rows below (11 cells in total).

Also it's possible to do this if you know the lowest cell in range and want to span it upwards. Specify the ending cell of your range and use negative value for `height` parameter:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(B20,0,0,-11))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Only thing that i need to add for the people who will see this is that if you want to use width, you should enter height parameter 1 rather than 0.I haven't heard offset before so it helped a lot.